# Foreach problem in controller - CodeIngiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, view, controller

Controller 'Photo' :

```
public function seePics(){
        // in $res, i have all the pictures in my table 'photo' (id, id_photograph, title, size...)
        $res = $this->Photo_model->readPhoto();

        // with the session, i have all the data that i need on the connected user
        $this->load->library('session');
        $data = $this->session->userdata('data');

        // user id
        $idUser = $data['id'];

        // here, i want to have only the picture of the connected user
        if(!sizeof($res) == 0){
            foreach($res as $item){
                if($item->id_user == $idUser){
                    $values['photo'] = $item;
                    $this->load->view('photo/voirPhoto', $values);
                }       
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('photo/aucunePhoto',$data);
        }
    }
```

View 'voirPhoto.php' : how i display data

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Title</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p><?php echo $photo->titre?></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p><?php echo $photo->name?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, my foreach is in my controller, but i want to do the foreach in my view. How can i do it ?

Because the problem I have, is : if the connected user have 3 pictures, it will display 3 times the views.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just filter the user here itself? `$res = $this->Photo_model->readPhoto();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Viney said, you can just filter user in query inside readPhoto function.
Like something that: `$res = $this->Photo_model->readPhoto($idUser)` 
and

```
public function readPhoto($idUser = null) 
{
    $query = "select * from photos " . (($idUser)? "where id_user = {$idUser}" : "");

    ...
}
```

So you will have all photos of the connected user.

If you wish catch just one row, you can use $res[0] I think or **first**  in your query (depends on the database).

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function seePics($id=null){   
    $query['my_query'] = "Select * from photos where id _user =".$id; 
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($my_query as $key=>$val){
   <?= $val['photo']?> //photo column name
}
```